# Standard tree (Bass-Serre theory)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm studying Bass-Serre theory using the book "Groups acting on graphs" of Dicks and Dunwoody. I'm having difficult to understand the construction of the standard tree (page 13). I'm trying to 'translate' it to a more simple language, but I don't know if it is correct. I'm follow the notations of the book unless the incidence maps which I denote by $d_0$ and $d_1$.

We have a graph of groups $(G(-),Y)$ with $Y$ connected and to define a graph on which the fundamental group of $(G(-),Y)$ acts. We choose a set $S$ which is the following disjoint union
$$S = \bigcup_{y \in Y}G/G_y$$
where $G_y$ are the stabilizer of $y$.
We have a bijection between $Gy$ (orbit set) and $G/G_y$. Define $V(S) = \{Gv : v \in V(Y)\}$ and $E(S) = \{Ge : e \in E(Y)\}$. We have the maps $d_0: E(S) \to V(S)$ given by $d_0(ge) = g\bar{d}_0(e)$ and $d_1:E(S) \to V(S)$ given by $d_1(ge) = gt_e\bar{d}_1(e)$ where $\bar{d}_i$ are the incidence maps of the connected graph $Y$. It is obvious that $d_0$ is well defined. The element $t_e$ was choosen such that $t_e\bar{d}_1(e) = \bar{d}_1(e)$ because $\bar{d}_1(e)$ and $d_1(e)$ are in the same orbit.